# action.setCallback not getting executed after $A.enqueueAction(action);

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have been stuck on this problem for two days now and it doesn't seem like I can figure this one out by myself. Need some help from the community...

I have been trying to get the return value from an apex method. Normally this can be done by calling the $A.enqueueAction(action) and this will then call the action.setCallBack method to give me back the return value of my apex method. By default, the return value is stored in response.getReturnValue().

But with my code, my $A.enqueueAction(action) did get executed but my action.setCallBack method never got executed. Without action.setCallBack method being called, I had no way of obtaining the return value from my apex method. Anyone here seen this problem before?

**Here's my helper controller:**

```
// EstimatorCalendarHelper.js
callServer : function(component, event, helper, startDateTime) {
    // some more code here 
    var action = component.get("c.convertTheLead");    
    action.setParams({ "eventRecord" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.newEvent")), "eventStartDateTime" : eventStartDateTime, "eventEndDateTime" : eventEndDateTime });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {            
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {     
            var oppID = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.oppID", response.getReturnValue());
        } 
        else {               
            console.log(state);
        }          
    });             
    $A.enqueueAction(action);  
}
```

**Here is my client side controller:**

```
// EstimatorCalendarController.js
handleValueChange : function(component, event, helper) {

   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({           
        // some code here
        select: function(startDate, endDate) {
            // some code here                           
            $("#eventContent").dialog({ modal: true, 
                                       width:750,
                                       buttons: {
                                           "Save Appointment" : function() {
                                               helper.callServer(component, event, helper, startDate);
                                               $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                                           
                                           },                                                  
                                           Cancel : function() {
                                               $( this ).dialog( "close" );                                                       
                                           }
                                       }
                                    });               
                                  }
                        })

}
```

**Here is my component:**

```
// EstimatorCalendar.cmp
<aura:component controller="CreateAppointmentController">
    <aura:attribute name="appointments" type="Event[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="oppID" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.appointments}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>        
    // Some more code here
</aura:component>
```

**Here is my Apex Controller:**

```
// CreateAppointmentController.apex
@AuraEnabled
public static String convertTheLead (String eventRecord, String eventStartDateTime, String eventEndDateTime) {
    Event newEventRecord = (Event)JSON.deserialize(eventRecord, Event.class);
    newEventRecord.StartDateTime = DateTime.valueof(eventStartDateTime);
    newEventRecord.EndDateTime = DateTime.valueof(eventEndDateTime);
    try {    
        insert newEventRecord;
    }
    catch (DMLException ex){
        system.debug( ex.getMessage());
    }         
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(newEventRecord.WhoId);
    LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
    Id oppId = lcr.getOpportunityId();
    String oppIDString = String.valueOf(oppId);
    return oppIDString;    
}
```

Comment: What about your apex controller? Have you done any debugging there?

Comment: Try using console.log in your callback function. Also post the apex, and do you get to see the request coming in through in apex?

Comment: I did tried to include console.log in my action.setCallback function but it's useless because my action.setCallback method didn't get executed and thus putting console.log in my action.setCallback just won't work.

Comment: What about apex? Do you see request coming in there and also do you see the oppIDString?

Comment: Just included my apex controller for you guys to see. I've already tested many times and confirmed that the DML operation is working as expected there. It is able to return a string. But my action.setCallback is not being executed and thus I am not able to get the return string.

Comment: Can you add the component from which you are calling the  handleValueChange()

Comment: Hi Ayub. I just updated my EstimatorCalendarController.js to include more details on how to call my helper function.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch it's because you're using jquery AND an external library that the order of operations is slightly outside of the lightning framework so your callback is not getting caught. See the following article:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm

My gut instinct is to wrap your callout with a getCallback, but I'm not 100% sure where you would wrap it when you're using that calendar library. Try wrapping the helper with something like this:

```
$A.getCallback(function() {
  helper.callServer(component, event, helper, startDate);
});
```

You can also use promises to get a little more granular control:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here are few inputs:

**EstimatorCalendarHelper.js**

```
callServer : function(component, event, helper, startDateTime) {
  action.setParams({ "eventRecord" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.newEvent")), "eventStartDateTime" : eventStartDateTime, "eventEndDateTime" : eventEndDateTime });
```

What are `eventStartDateTime` and `eventEndDateTime` here? I guess you forgot the pass it to `callServer` from the controller...

So you can go with the `controller`, the `startDate`, and `endDate` like below:

**EstimatorCalendarHelper.js**

```
callServer : function(component, eventStartDateTime, eventEndDateTime) {
  // some more code here 
  var action = component.get("c.convertTheLead");    
  action.setParams({ "eventRecord" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.newEvent")), "eventStartDateTime" : eventStartDateTime, "eventEndDateTime" : eventEndDateTime });
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {            
    var state = response.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {     
        var oppID = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.oppID", response.getReturnValue());
    } 
    else {               
        console.log(state);
    }          
  });             
  $A.enqueueAction(action);  
}
```

**EstimatorCalendarController.js**
    /* more controller code here */

```
"Save Appointment" : function() {
   helper.callServer(component, startDate, endDate);
},

/* more controller code here */
```

And if it still doesn't work then do check for the errors and share if you get any.

Comment: The arguments that I pass into my callServer function are correct. They are not the issue. Thanks for your input anyway Itzmukeshy7.